# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript

below is my code for navigation

```
         export class AppComponent {
           router:Router
            doSwipe(direction: string){

               this.router.navigate(['/article']);
            }
       }
```

I am getting Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined error.pls help to fix it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to inject the router, not just declare it as a property

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I injected the router inside the constructor using the @Inject annotation.

```
constructor(@Inject(Router) private router: Router) {}
```

Comment: why we need this.is there any purpose of using @Inject(Router).Because without using this its working fine.is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `Router` in constructor:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    doSwipe(direction: string) {

        this.router.navigate(['/article']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the router inside the **`constructor`**,

```
constructor(
     private router: Router
){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but in my case I had Fabio answer,
but forgot to add @autoInject()

so you have to add

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject()
export class YourClass {
     
     constructor(private router: Router) {}

}
```