# Navigation - Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm trying to navigate on 'Home' route after the login function and I tried to integrate the navigate function in login but I have the error 'Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined error'.

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {
    try {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function(user) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.toString());
    }
};
```

I have also tried to user `() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");` but nothing happens.

My routes are working fine because if I create a simple button with onPress function, is working fine.

`<Button title="Go to Login" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")} />`

Could you please give me some hints? How to navigate to Home page after the login is success in react-native?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is `loginUser` is actions of redux ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689606/cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838595/cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined-in-react-navigation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838595/cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined-in-react-navigation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196824/cannot-read-property-navigate-of-undefined-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the lexical scope of ***this*** (in this.props) when you use the function() {} syntax vs the arrow-function syntax in your promise-chain.

If you change the function to an arrow function, you'll retain the outer scope, and have access to *this*.

e.g

```
.then((user) => {
   that.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @codi05ro - I really need to see more of your code unfortunately. Can you what specifically is undefined? If you console.log(this.props) on the first-line of the loginUser method - are you able to see navigation there?

Answer (score 1):

Try to console.log(this).I thought because you create a new function in the promise,the scope of this has been changed.Try

`loginUser = (email, password) => {
    let that = this;
    try {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function(user) {
                that.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.toString());
    }
};`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried but now I get 'that is not defined'